# Will the dcc32.exe compiler use project build configuration file when is called with --no-config parameter?

Tags: delphi, build, delphi-2009, buildconfiguration, dcc32

***Problem description:***

Consider the following command line call (called for Delphi 2009 compiler):

```
dcc32.exe --no-config --peflags:1 Project.dpr
```

Will this call use the `Project.dproj` or `Project.dof` configuration files ?

- If yes, will the command line options take precedence over the configuration file(s) ?
- If not, where the build configuration will be taken from if the dcc32.cfg file is not loaded in this case ?

***Problem background:***

I know that MSBuild should be used since Delphi 2007 but in fact, it's the reason why I'm asking. I found that InnoSetup uses [`this batch file`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/compile-unicode.bat) for building its projects and I have serious problems to link the JEDI JVCL library to it (it's a pure nightmare). So I'd like to configure the project settings to use MSBuild, but I'm not sure what build settings are used in the above command line call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`--no-config` means that dcc32.cfg is not loaded, neither from the compiler executable directory, nor from the project directory.

The rules for applying options specified in .dproj and .dof files are not affected. Those options are applied and any command line options take precedence.